# Ionic Push notification

Tags: push-notification, ionic-framework, push

I try to Sending Push Notification with Ionic.io.

so I do than this demo: https://devdactic.com/android-push-notifications/

But when I Run in android, I have this error:

> app.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Ionic.User.anonymousId is not a function

this is my index.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- Cordova is bootstrapped by ionic-platform-web-client, uncomment this if you remove ionic-platform-web-client... -->
<!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my app.js:

```
  // Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.service.core', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ionic.service.push'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        var io = Ionic.io();
        var push = new Ionic.Push({
            "onNotification": function (notification) {
                alert('Received push notification!');
            },
            "pluginConfig": {
                "android": {
                    "iconColor": "#0000FF"
                }
            }
        });
        var user = Ionic.User.current();

        if (!user.id) {
            user.id = Ionic.User.anonymousId();
        }

        // Just add some dummy data..
        user.set('name', 'Simon');
        user.set('bio', 'This is my little bio');
        user.save();

        var callback = function (data) {
            push.addTokenToUser(user);
            user.save();
        };
        push.register(callback);


    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

I have only follow this instruction:

> ionic start devdactic-android-push cd devdactic-android-push ionic add
>   ionic-platform-web-client ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
>   --variable SENDER_ID=your-gcm-project-number ionic io init
>
> ionic push --google-api-key your-google-api-key ionic config set
>   gcm_key your-gcm-project-number ionic config set dev_push false

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You might just want to start with trying the limited push setup, Ionic provides their own guide for it which is really easy to follor:

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-limited-setup

If you got that figured out, you can send a notification to your app and the app will open an alert message with the notification content. Then you can start using native pushes, which requires allmost the same code:

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-full-setup

And here is a guide on how to send pushes using the ionic.io framework:

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push